# How to use typeahead?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am trying to use twitter typeahead.js in my laravel app. It doesn't work (no error, but nothing appear under my field).

So I decided to to a simple html file with just the librairies and the examples (https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) to test.
And this doesn't work either.

I'm going crazy :/ Is there something obvious I don't see ?

This is my code :

```
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.min.css"
        integrity="sha256-CU0/rbxVB3Eixd3bbIuJxHJLDnXriJS9cwp/BfcgpLw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="bloodhound">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-W+Cxk9exgjON2p73M4RcoKvCpQUZ+IjXhEzZk6rlg9M=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.2.1/bloodhound.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-WJlyUMyJDhWTumC7/oaAtXFRBh0rZGc7qT80egxJafw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>



        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
            'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
            'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
            'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
            'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
            'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
            'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
            'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        // constructs the suggestion engine
        var states = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
            local: states
        });

        $('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
            {
                name: 'states',
                source: states
            });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Link to test : https://jsfiddle.net/rxybp8de/2/

Comment: There are [401 open issues](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) and it was last updated 5 years ago -  I suggest that you switch to other library that is being maintained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused by the library versions you are using in the fiddle.

In the typeahead examples they seem to use jQuery 1.10.2 while you are using a more advanced version.

Furthermore, you are using a `jquery.typeahead.min.js` plugin that seems to not be the same as the `typeahead.jquery.js` plugin that is used in the typeahead documentation pages (note the change in order of the plugins names).

I built this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40az9owv/) in which I only changed those libraries and it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mgarcia

Comment: Glad to help :)